# how to create log file for tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am running Tcl script for connecting Telnet port. For this script I want to store all the CMD output in a log file. how to do this in Tcl script? Script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!usr/bin/expect
package require Expect
spawn telnet $serverName $portNum
expect "TradeAggregator>"
send "Clients\r"
expect "Client:"
send "1\r"
expect "1-Client>"
send "Pollers\r"
expect "Client Pollers"
send "2\r"
send "n\r"
expect ">"
set passwordOption $expect_out(buffer)
set searchString "Not confirmed" 
if {[string match *$searchString* $passwordOption]} { 
puts "match found" }\ 
else { 
puts "match not found" 
xmlPasswordChange $polName 
}
```

all the puts output and xmlPasswordChange procedure output is not printing in the log file. can you please point out where i am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to insert a `log_file` command where you want to start saving the output. For example, if you want to save all the output, then stick it to the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

log_file myfile.log ;# <<< === append output to a file

package require Expect
spawn telnet $serverName $portNum
expect "TradeAggregator>"
send "Clients\r"
expect "Client:"
send "1\r"
expect "1-Client>"
send "Pollers\r"
expect "Client Pollers"
send "2\r"
```

Be default, `log_file` appends if the file exists, or create a new one. If you want to start a new log every time, then:

```
log_file -noappend myfile.log
```

#### Update

Per your question regarding why `puts` outputs go to the console and not the log file. The way I understand is `puts` will go to the console. If you want to log to the log file (open that was opened with the `log_file` command), then use the `send_log` command instead:

```
log_file -noappend myfile.log
send_log "This line goes into the log file"
send_user "This line goes into both the log file and console\n"
puts "This line goes to the console"
```

The above example introduced another command: `send_user`, which acts like `puts` and `send_log` combined. Note that `send_user` does not include a new line, so the caller should include it.

Comment: @Vu - i am sending the below command then checking the if else condition for calling one procedure. script calling is working and printing the puts in CMD  of that calling procedure but not in log_myfile.log file.
`send "n\r"
expect ">"
 
#expect * ;#this is for to get data in expect_out
set passwordOption $expect_out(buffer)
#puts "$passwordOption"
set searchString "Not confirmed"
if {[string match *$searchString* $passwordOption]} {
puts "match found"
}\
else {
puts "match not found"
xmlPasswordChange $polName
}`

how can i print all CMD output in log file?

Comment: Can you update your main post with this information? I am not good at reading text like this. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Vu - i have added in main post my problem. can you please look into this.

Comment: thanks a ton Vu. after replacing puts with send_user it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Also We can create our own log file by stranded [open $file_name w] command and keep writing everything to that file.